# how can create a directory, in add site command using appcmd.exe?

Tags: iis, command-prompt, appcmd

When I am using the appcmd.exe for creating a website, I need a physical Path address in the command. How can I create directory when I am running this address:

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe add site /name:websitename /id:4 /physicalPath:C:\inetpub\wwwroot\example12 /bindings:http/*:80:example.com
```

On above command, "example12" directory doesn`t exist. And I want when running a command, that directory creating that address Automatically.

Comment: You cannot. Use `mkdir` to create that folder before calling `appcmd`.

Comment: AppCmd.exe is the single command line tool for managing IIS, It cannot create a directory. more information about the use of appcmd you can refer to this link: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe).